# Sitecore SPEAK UI programmatically set selected item of ComboBox

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-speak-ui

How should I set the selected item of a ComboBox component in Sitecore SPEAK UI?

My ComboBox is populated by a QueryDataSource component which is looking at a folder of items in my core DB.

I can retrieve the currently selected value (which is text, not an ID) using the following code:

```
var value = this.MyComboBoxId.viewModel.selectedItemId();
```

and I would have expected to be able to set the selected value using:

```
var value = "SomeValueWhichExistsInTheList";
this.MyComboBoxId.viewModel.selectedItemId(value);
```

but this doesn't seem to work. The documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/components/combobox) mentions using

```
rebind(items, selectedItem, selectedValue, displayFieldName, valueFieldName)
```

but I don't want to have to re-populate it, just change the selected item. My code is within the `initialize` method of my model.

**Edit**

I found that if the ComboBox does not have `DisplayFieldName` or `ValueFieldName` values set in the rendering properties you have to set the value to the appropriate itemId. `DisplayFieldName` and/or `ValueFieldName` should be set to the name of a field you have created - you cannot bind to the item name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `initialize` method, use the following code to set the value:

```
app.yourQueryDataSource.on("change:hasItems", function () {
    app.yourComboBox.set("selectedValue", yourValue); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Above approach did not work for me and hence i used the

```js
app.<yourcontrolid>.viewModel.rebind()
```

function as documented in Sitecore SPEAK combobox documentation and that worked.